# Why won't $ match in this regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-lookarounds

I have the following line, that separates the frames in a GIF file:

```
preg_match_all('/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04)/s', $fileContents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

If you're familiar with the GIF file format, you might notice a major flaw in this - it won't detect the last frame, because the lookahead is only for the frame header.

If, instead, I change the regular expression to this: `'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04|\x3B$)/s`, where `\x3B` is the file terminator (followed by the actual end of the file/string), the entire thing fails, and it can't even match once.

I've *sort of* tested this in Kodos, but since this is binary data, the best I could do was a plain-text equivalent, which worked exactly as expected. The function `preg_match('/\x00\x3B$/', $fileContents)` *does* match as it should, and analysis of the file in a hex editor confirms that it is laid out as it ought to be.

So, then, why does adding `|\x3B$` to the lookahead make it fail entirely?

Note: Yes, there are libraries for working with gif images. This question is purely about process, not end results.

**EDIT:** It came to my attention that the pipespace might not actually the problem; the regex is happy to match either `\x00\x21\xF9\x04` *or* `\x3B` (which isn't useful, because `\x3B` appears alone many times throughout the file). The problem seems to occur with multiple characters after the pipespace... sort of. `\x3B$` and `\x00\x3B` will both cause the entire regex to fail. However, just looking for $ fails no matter what. This seems to be more an issue with the $ anchor than anything else, though that's apparently not the only thing screwy here.

Permutations that result in **0** matches:

```
//Grouping within lookahead:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=(\x00\x21\xF9\x04|\x3B$))/s'
//Moving lookahead within frame subpattern:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?(?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04|\x3B$))/s'
//Both of the above:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?(?=(\x00\x21\xF9\x04|\x3B$)))/s'
//Separating to two lookaheads:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)((?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04)|(?=\x3B$))/s'
//Just looking for the end anchor without \x3B:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04|$)/s'
//Just trying to find the end of the file:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=$)/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)$/s'
//Trying to find \x00\x3B, the last two bytes:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04|\x00\x3B)/s'
//With some more grouping experiments:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=(\x00\x21\xF9\x04|\x00\x3B))/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=(\x00\x21\xF9\x04)|(\x00\x3B))/s'
//Moving file end outside of lookahead:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)((?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04)|$)/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)((?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04)|\x3B$)/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)((?=\x00\x21\xF9\x04)|\x00\x3B)/s'
//Moving file end before header:
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=$|\x00\x21\xF9\x04)/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=\x3B$|\x00\x21\xF9\x04)/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=\x00\x3B|\x00\x21\xF9\x04)/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=($)|(\x00\x21\xF9\x04))/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=(\x3B$)|(\x00\x21\xF9\x04))/s'
'/(?P<frame>\x00\x21\xF9\x04.(?P<delay>..).\x00\x2C.*?)(?=(\x00\x3B)|(\x00\x21\xF9\x04))/s'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to group your pipe separated values in a pair of their own parentheses:

```
(?=(a|b))
```

Comment: Tried that (and most other permutations), with no success. Kodos also doesn't indicate a need for it.